# Collapse successive alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: python, string

I would like to find an elegant and efficient way to concatenate all successive occurrences of single alphanumeric characters separated by white space within a string into words. Here is an example of what I want to do:

```
a = 'a b c zzz a yyy a 2 xxx 2 3 wwww a c'
```

Desired_result = `'abc zzz a yyy a2 xxx 23 wwww ac'`

Here is what I have using loops but I am sure there is some elegant solution.

```
def myFunc(instring):
    b,result = instring.split(),''
    for i,row in enumerate(b):
        if i==0:
            result = row
        else:
            if len(row) == 1 and len(b[i-1]) == 1 and \
             row.isalnum() and b[i-1].isalnum():
                result = result + row
            else:
                result = result + ' ' + row
    else:           
        return result

a = 'a b c zzz a yyy a 2 xxx 2 3 wwww a c'
print myFunc(a)

a_punct = '! @ 23 xxx cv abd $ abcd a c #'
print myFunc(a_punct)
```

Comment: How should single non-alphanumerics (i.e. punctuation marks) be handled?

Comment: My apologies. I was reading an ASCII encoded text and already replacing non-alphanumeric characters with blank space. I have updated the post (and my own function) to correct for the oversight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a regex solution:

```
>>> a = 'a b c zzz a yyy a 2 xxx 2 3 wwww a c'
>>> re.sub(r'(?<=\b\w)\s+(?=\w\b)', '', a)
'abc zzz a yyy a2 xxx 23 wwww ac'
```

It removes any whitespace (`\s+`) that is preceded by a single alphanumeric character (`(?<=\b\w)`) and followed by a single alphanumeric character (`(?=\w\b)`). The `\w` is an alphanumeric character or underscore (replace it with `[a-zA-Z0-9]` for alphanumeric only), and the `\b` is a word boundary, which makes sure the alphanumeric character isn't followed/preceded by another one.

Answer (score 2):

```
from itertools import groupby
print(" ".join(["".join(v) if k == 1 else " ".join(v)
                for k, v in groupby(a.split(), key=len)]))
abc zzz a yyy a2 xxx 23 wwww ac
```

If you actually can have non single alphanumeric characters which your own code does not check for you can use a lambda:

```
     key=lambda x: len(x) == 1 and x.isalnum()
```

Comment: Only single _alphanumeric_ characters should be concatenated. OTOH, the OP's test string doesn't contain any non-blank, non-alphanumerics...

Comment: @PM2Ring.  the OP does not check so I presume the alphanumeric part of the question is noise

Comment: This should say `if k==1`, otherwise it will also concatenate "aaa bbb"

Comment: @interjay,  `key=lambda x: len(x) == 1`,`if k == 1` is the same as saying `if k`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham But in your original code you use `key=len`, which means `if k` will always be true. You can fix it by either using `if k==1`, or by using your lambda.

Comment: @interjay, sorry, yes I misunderstood what you were saying

Answer (score 0):

Well, that depends on your definition of elegant. You could iterate over the result of the `split`, build up items of length one to bigger items and directly append longer items.

```
current_item = []
result = []

for item in instring.split():
    if len(item) == 1:
        current_item.append(item)
    elif len(item) > 1 and current_item:
        result.append("".join(current_item))
        current_item = []
        result.append(item)
    else:
        result.append(item)

if current_item:
    result.append("".join(current_item))

print " ".join(result)
```

By using creating the items as lists and joining them at the end you avoid a lot of string concatenations, which are very inefficient in python. As strings are immutable objects, each time you use a string concatenation with the `+` operator a new string is created in memory and the content of the two original strings are copied into it.
A list on the other hand can be dynamically changed in size and you only have to create the string object once at the end.